# How to add items in spinners with a parent - child relationship?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I have two spinners in my android app. One for selecting a *chain* and other for selecting *stores*. I want to add items to both spinners. The items of second spinner is dependent to first spinner, i.e. items of *stores* should be dependent on the selected *chain* item. I have tried for same but items of store are empty. Please help me - here's my code I've tried:

```
private class ChainDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Chain>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SelectStoreActivity.this, null, "Loading Chains...");
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Chain> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // call web method to get all chains
            CallSoap cs = new CallSoap();
            ArrayList<Chain> chainList = cs.getAllChains();
            return chainList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Chain> result) {
            mArrayListChains = result;
            loadChainSpinner();
            new StoresDownloadTask().execute();
        }
    }

    private class StoresDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Store>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Stores...");
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Store> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // call web method to get all chains
            CallSoap cs = new CallSoap();
            ArrayList<Store> chainList = cs.getAllStores();
            return chainList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Store> result) {
            mArrayListStores = result;
            loadStoreSpinner(mArrayListChains.get(0).getId());
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void loadChainSpinner() {
        ArrayList<String> chainNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Chain temp : mArrayListChains) {
            chainNameList.add(temp.getName());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectStoreActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, chainNameList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinnerChain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void loadStoreSpinner(int chainId) {
        ArrayList<Store> storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
        ArrayList<String> storeNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Store store : mArrayListStores) {
            if((""+chainId).equals(store.getChainID())){
                storeList.add(store);
                storeNameList.add(store.getFld_str_Name());
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectStoreActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, storeNameList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinnerStores.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

[image]`

Comment: check whether storeNameList is empty or not.

Comment: Store name list is not empty. Values are coming from web server.

Comment: Do you initialize mSpinnerStores? Could you please share the url for spinner items?

Comment: Actually I am testing on localhost.

Comment: there is some problem with 
      if((""+chainId).equals(store.getChainID()))
add a println to check whether the condition ever true or not

Comment: wait....I am checking it..

Answer (score 0):

Check following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < Counter; i++) {
        strPromoterNames[i] = promoterDetailsResponse.Sub_promoters.get(i).SubpromoterName;
}


       ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPromoterDetails = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strPromoterNames);
       adapterPromoterDetails.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinnerPromoterDetails.setAdapter(adapterPromoterDetails);
```